# Need help in Self Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I've a Table **XYZ**:

```
ID   A       B       C
1    abc     ygh     NULL
2    fgfd    bjh     NULL
3    jhkj    fgd     cgbvc
1    NULL    NULL    yr
2    NULL    NULL    jg
```

I need to do a self join on the above table to get only the matching IDs. I'm trying to use below query:

```
Select T1.ID, T1.A, T1.B, T2.C
From XYZ T1
INNER JOIN XYZ T2
where T1.ID = T2.ID
```

But not getting below result:

```
1   abc     ygh     yr
2   fgfd    bjh     jg
```

Please advise. Krishna

Comment: Is it always that A, B are null or C is null?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use `self join`.

**`Tip: 'A' + NULL=NULL`**

```
select ID,max(A) A,max(B) B,max(C) C
from XYZ
where A+B+C is null
group by ID
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6eedc/1)**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like that:

```
select T1.ID, T1.A, T1.B, T2.C from XYZ T1
inner join XYZ T2
on T1.ID = T2.ID
where T1.A is not null and T1.B is not null and T2.C is not null
```

As the join to itself will give you all the combinations of `T1` and `T2`, you want the one where all columns are not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query but its based on WHERE clause.

```
select ID,A,B,C from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by s desc ) as 'x' from (
Select  T1.ID,T1.A,T1.B,T2.C,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.id order by     
t1.a,t1.b ,t1.c ) as s
From xyz T1 JOIN xyz T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID ) abc ) xyz
where x = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this table structure, you could also use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.A, b.A) A,
    COALESCE(a.B, b.B) B,
    COALESCE(a.C, b.C) C
FROM 
    XYZ a 
JOIN 
    XYZ b ON a.Id = b.Id
WHERE
    a.A IS NULL OR a.B IS NULL OR a.C IS NULL
```